# CakePHP -> How to right use findAll with Joined Table?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

i have got 3 tables

User
UserHasBasicTheme (join table user.id, user_theme.id)
UserTheme

I would like to use findAll method to get All UserTheme by given user.id

Each table has own model.

I tried to do by using:

```
$this->UserTheme->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UserHasBasicTheme')));
 $this->UserTheme->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('UserHasBasicTheme.user_id' => $this->id)
 ));
```

But example below is returning error:
Call to a member function bindModel() on a non-object

Im calling it on User controller.

I would like to ask, how would that be correct?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It would be `$this->User->UserTheme`

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem Call to a member function find() on a non-object.

Comment: Please state the relation between them clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the $uses property defined?

```
public $uses = array('UserTheme', 'User', 'UserHasBasicTheme');
```

for the controller?